# Find the value based on combination of different columns and row

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have created a sheet, that anyone can access (if you can copy and make the edit in yours, then that would be appreciated) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rWDpWSROslNLzgMLi7P4PSqFZwRsA-kJxvhqfBoFP-4/edit#gid=0 In that sheet, I am trying to calculate a value based on the data in the different sheet there.
Below, you can see my "Expense" sheet where I am looking to get a calculated value in column D (shaded blue color) based on selected values in A, B, and C.

[image: Expense calculation sheet]

And data is in the sheet Roles-location-salary.
Please note, in that sheet, the salary values are per year, but in the "Expense" sheet I need to have it divided by 12 to get the monthly value.

[image: data values]

I tried taking inspiration from Vlookup, but could not get it to work. Any help will be appreciated as to what the formula could be?

Comment: On my phone but this should get you rolling. Google for INDEX/MATCH/MATCH examples and look at the function documentation for INDEX and MATCH (namely what parameters they take). Then Google how to do a multi-criteria MATCH for Role+Department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestion

You can try a combination of `IF`,`VLOOKUP`,`HLOOKUP`, & `MATCH` formulas to achieve your goal:

***Method***

***[UPDATED]***

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(B2,'Roles-location-salary'!A:Q,2,FALSE) = A2, HLOOKUP(C2,'Roles-location-salary'!A:Q,MATCH(B2, 'Roles-location-salary'!A:A,0),FALSE),'Roles-location-salary'!R1)/12
```

### Demonstration

> [image]***The value returned was divided by 12 to get the monthly value***

### References

- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375)
- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)

Comment: Any particular advantage you are seeking with VLOOKUP + TRANSPOSE instead of HLOOKUP?

Comment: @MarkBalhoff Ohh I wasn't aware of that particular function. Thanks for pointing this one out to me. I appreciate it.

Comment: Hello Irvin Jay G. Thank you so much for spending time in providing the solution. Appreciate it. There is one situation, where this formula is not working. If I select a combination of "department", "location" and "salary", whose data, I don't have then the value should become $0. But it still holds the older value. As you can see here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rWDpWSROslNLzgMLi7P4PSqFZwRsA-kJxvhqfBoFP-4/edit#gid=0&range=D2

Comment: @JVK You're welcome. I have updated my answer & please try to test it to see if the returns `$0` if **department**, **location** and **salary** do not match on your end. I used the `VLOOKUP` to be checked inside the `IF` formula if the **department** selected matches the actual adjacent department from the **location** and **salary**, otherwise, it will return `$0` since there are no exact matches.

Comment: Thank you Irvin. I accepted your answer. You are awesome.